# How do you find the angle between vector $\vec b-\vec a$ and the $x$-axis, given the angles of $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ with the $x$-axis?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

How do you find the angle between vector $\vec b-\vec a$ and the $x$-axis given that $\vec a$ has a length equal to $1$ and an angle of $10^\circ$ with the $x$-axis and $\vec b$ has a length of $1$ and an angle equal to $40^\circ$ with the $x$-axis?

The use of a calculator is forbidden so you can't just calculate the coordinates of $\vec a - \vec b$ simply by entering $(\cos 40^\circ - \cos 10^\circ, \sin 40^\circ - \sin 10 ^\circ)$ in a calculator. So what other approaches can I take?

Comment: You can form a triangle $OAB$. It is isosceles and you can find the required angle by geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a solution without using any calculator.
in this picture,

$OA$ is vector b and

$OB $ is vector a.

and $BA$ is vector b-a

[image]

as in the image, you can see that $\triangle OAB$ is an isosceles triangle because of $OA=OB$

thus the $\angle OAB=\angle OBA$

so $\angle OAB=75 $ sum of all three angle is 180

calculate $\angle OBC$ WHICH IS 105 degree

thus$ \angle OCB=65$ thus your vector makes 115 degrees with the x-axis

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

Draw a triangle $\triangle{OAB}$ with end poinst of $\vec{a}$ as $A$ and $\vec{b}$ as $B$. Angle between $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ is $30^{\circ}$. Also $|\vec{a}|=|\vec{b}|$. So the other two angles are $75^{\circ}$. Can you now use geometry to find angle between $\vec{b}-\vec{a}$ and $x$ axis?